# Emacs: Shell command on region without prompt for user input

Tags: bash, emacs

Suppose I editing a file that ends with a ".sh" (bash)
I select a region with ESC Shift-| which leads to the minibuffer
asking me "Shell command on region:". I don't want to say "bash" all the time but instead would like "bash" to be executed without prompt for user input. Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: Create a keyboard macro that does it.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because emacs.stackexchange.com is a better place to ask about using Emacs commands.

Comment: `C-x ( M-| bash RET C-x )`